# Enforcing data type while creating dataframe with known bad data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to manipulate a simple csv file (from one of Stanford Uni Stats self-paced course). The dataset has an int type column which contains '*' when there is no data for the column. Is there a way to enforce datatype as I create the dataframe for this dataset? It seems that Python finds the * which not being an int errors out. My intent is to enforce int data type (either at dataframe creation time or later) so that I can do some descriptive stats on data as int)

```
df = pd.read_csv('drinking.csv', delimiter=',', header=1, error_bad_lines=False,
                 names=['Gender', 'Alcohol', 'Height', 'Cheat'], 
                 dtype={"Gender": str, "Alcohol": int, "Height": int, "Cheat": bool}, 
                 na_values=['*'], keep_default_na=False, usecols=['Alcohol'])
```

This code fails to accept the dtype. 'Alcohol' is int and when result frame has a * it fails
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 1

My point is that I should be able to enforce int data type at some stage, if not while creating dataframe, then some time before I want to call df.describe()

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is a float, which cannot be stored in a normal `int`. You can use the `Int64` dtype (notice the capital I) that was introduced in `0.24`.

#### Sample Data, `test.csv`

```
id,bad_col
1,10
2,20
3,*
4,*
5,50
```

---

```
# Reproduce error
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='*', dtype={'bad_col': int})
#ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 1

# Read in properly
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='*', dtype={'bad_col': 'Int64'})
#   id  bad_col
#0   1       10
#1   2       20
#2   3      NaN
#3   4      NaN
#4   5       50

# True data remain int
type(df.bad_col.iloc[0])
#numpy.int64

# Missing data are float
type(df.bad_col.iloc[3])
#float
```